# chrome.tabs.update – insert URL without percentage encoding

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to program a small Chrome extension that performs URL manipulation and changes the path of a URL. Everything works so far, but not when parameters are involved.

Data is saved in a list. After clicking on a list entry, the path of the URL of the current tab is replaced by the saved data.

However, if a path is saved with a question mark, a %3F is always inserted.

How can I fix this error?

```
function updateList(items) {
      listElement.innerHTML = '';
      items.forEach(function(item, index) {
        const listItem = document.createElement('li');
  
        const pathText = document.createElement('span');
        pathText.textContent = item.description;
        pathText.classList.add('path-text');
        pathText.addEventListener('click', function() {
          chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            const tab = tabs[0];
            const url = new URL(tab.url);
            url.pathname = '/' + item.path;
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: url.toString()});
            });
        });
```

To rule out the possibility that it is due to the browser, I changed the URL manually in the source code as a test. This also works:

```
let myNewUrl = 'https://www.test.de/test?formatc';
chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { url: myNewUrl });
```

The URL is inserted exactly as written in the source code.

I thank you in advance!

I found something on the web about decodeURIComponent and encodeURIComponent and tried it out. Unfortunately, what I did did not work.

Comment: `?` can't be a part of `pathname` because it's for `search`.

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean. For example, I would like to replace a WordPress URL (backend). To access the pages is the following path: `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page`.

So question marks in URL are not only there for search ?!...

Comment: Only `/wp-admin/edit.php` is pahname here, while `?post_type=page` is `search`. This is how `URL` API works.

Comment: Ah. Now I've understood. Can you give me a hint as to how I can solve my problem in another way?

Comment: It's your decision. You can strip that part, you can replace `?` with a valid symbol.